# In shiny's selectizeInput, is it imperative to click on a highligthed option to choose it?

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny, selectize.js

I have an app with many selectizeInput fields that I would like the user to fill in quickly using the arrow keys to highlight an option from the drop-down menu, then press `tab` and have shiny record that value. It is annoying that in order to select a highlighted option from the drop-down menu of a selecizeInput field you have to click on it (or press `Enter`).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  selectizeInput("sex", "sex", choices = c("m","f")),
  selectizeInput("age", "age", choices = c("< 15",">15")),
  selectizeInput("location", "location", choices = c("africa", "other"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I had to move to other things.